# Hosting asp.net web application in Linux environment

Tags: asp.net, linux, tomcat, iis-8.5

We have an asp.net application with framework 4.5 that is currently hosted in Windows server with IIS 8.5, SQL server as backend. it is a simple web application with forms authentication.

We are now planning to move to a Linux VM environment (tomcat server) not cloud, so I was wondering if we have to make any code changes. We are also not sure as to how to migrate to this new environment.

If anyone here can guide me to any article or if you have any inputs please do share.

PS: The exact configuration of the new VM is not finalised.

Comment: .net 4.5 u can not host on Linux, u have to upgrade to .net standard  or .net core

Comment: Agreed with Dreamweaver (where have I heard that name before???). Let Scott Hanselmann guide you through it: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx. Remember though that you MUST migrate to .net standard or .net core. You can start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/